# C-programming: From string to array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program which gets a string from the user, and stores it in an array. The program should not allow more than five names to be store, and not have more than ten characters per name. I'm able to compile this program, but when I run it and choose option "1", the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" comes up. The program should also show the list of names under option "2". (I guess i have to put most of the code in a do-while loop that run as long as iSelect != 3.)

What am I doing wrong here?

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char cList[20][5];
    char string[10];
    int iNum = 0;
    int iSelect = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    printf("\n\n*** Friend List ***\n\nWhat will you do?\n\n1. Write a friends name in the list.\n2. Print out the names in the list.\n3. Quit\n---> ");
    scanf("%d ", iSelect);

    switch(iSelect) {
    case 1:
        // printf("\n\nWrite name nr %d (max 10 characters): \n", iNum);
        scanf(" %s", &string);
        for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            cList[i][iNum] = string[i];
        }
        iNum++;
        break;

    case 2:
        for(j = 0 ; j <= iNum ; j++) {
            for(k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++) {
                printf("%c", cList[k][j]);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

} //End of main()-function
```

Comment: Learn how to use debugger. It will save you time in the future.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ would help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
char cList[10][5]; //You said client names 10 char maximum so [10][5] instead of [20][5]
char string[10];
int iNum = 0;
int iSelect = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;


do{
printf("\n\n*** Friend List ***\n\nWhat will you do?\n\n1. Write a friends name in the list.\n2. Print out the names in the list.\n3. Quit\n---> ");
scanf("%d ", &iSelect); //&iSelect instead of iSelect

switch(iSelect) {
case 1:
    if (iNum != 5){ //When iNum is 5 it's because cList is full. You can't add another name
    scanf("%s", &string);
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        cList[i][iNum] = string[i];
    }
    iNum++;
    }
    else{
    printf("Your list is full"); //cList can contain maximum 5 names.
    }
    break;

case 2:
    for(j = 0 ; j <= iNum ; j++) {
        for(k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++) {
            printf("%c", cList[k][j]);
        }
    }
    break;
}
}while(iSelect != 3); //keeps your app running until user presses option 3
}
```

I helped you a little with your code but I think what you should do is to use dynamic memory. You said names can't be longer than 10 chars but what if every name is 5 char lenght?

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You! You were the closest one to the solution I was looking for. I had to make string and cList global, and then it worked!

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("%d ", iSelect);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d ", &iSelect);
```

scanf expects a pointer to int in this case, not an int!

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler was likely trying to help you here:

```
(nick@gorgeous)-(~/Desktop)
(502)-> gcc test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
test.c:16: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
test.c:23: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’
test.c:23: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’
```

Don't ignore warnings, it told you 2 lines you have problems on, and what it found wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

As there is already good answers for your question I will just add two little advice for this project or others :

You can use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function to copy one char[] into another char[].

You can also allocate memory at runtime for your char[] using [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)

```
  char * string = "A sample String";
  char* copy;

  copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string));
  strcpy(copy,string);

  printf("%s", copy);
```

In your case you can use the result of `scanf` as `string`